# How do Human-Twi'lek hybrids work in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, biology, genetics, hybrid

So, Twi'lek hybrids have appeared in Star Wars Canon in two mediums. The animated Clone Wars and the recent live-action Ahsoka TV series. In the Clone Wars, a clone trooper deserts and marries a pink Twi'lek female. He is able to produce two children who look mostly like Twi'leks except for a few subtle differences. The boy has eyebrows which full Twi'lek males lack and the girl has mottled skin. However, they look mostly like Twi'leks.

Now we look at the hybrid, Jacen Syndulla, son of Human Jedi Kanan Jarrus and Twi'lek mother Hera Syndulla. Jacen looks FULLY human except for his hair color (which is green) that reflects his mother's skin color and is a hue that baseline humans cannot have naturally.

My question is. Why such glaring differences? Is it like here on Earth, where biracial children's looks depend solely on the roll of the die? But they are the same species? Humans and Twi'lek are separate species that evolved convergently, but on different planets. Would hybridization imply that Twi'leks and humans are actually the same genus? Are the Lawquane children and Jacen sterile?

Also, there is evidence for NO external medical genetic tampering. The clone deserter did not have accessed to advanced technology on Ryloth (Star Wars doesn't do that type of stuff usually, and Genetic engineering is mentioned to be illegal in the Mandalorian Season 3) and Hera did not know she was pregnant before Kanan died. They were obviously sleeping together but had no plans to start a family.

Comment: Very well, thanks for asking.

Comment: Just wanna point out that Cut Lawquane (the clone deserter) didn't have biological children with his wife. Jek and Shaeeah were human/Twi'lek hybrids but were from their mother's previous relationship, not their adoptive clone trooper dad. But the genetics issue of why there's so much variety still stands.

Comment: It really is strange that this question, which is totally valid, has two downvotes. Was this another one of those "haters love to downvote" incidents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Unknown. The ins and outs of such genetic combinations in Star Wars is never directly addressed.

**Rather Longer Answer:** Star Wars isn't sci-fi, nor is it meant to be. It's a space fantasy fairy-tale, with a general focus on mythic and folkloric storytelling, so try and remember that it's best to engage with it on those terms. Going looking for hard sci-fi answers to such things is generally an unproductive enterprise. Just accept that it's possible, and since literally nobody ever seems to comment on it, that it's a widely accepted and perfectly normal phenomenon.

If one were so inclined, one could certainly speculate any number of possible explanations, but speculation is all it can be for now.
For example; I like to think that most if not all of the "basically human faces with prosthetics and/or make-up" species (Chiss, Togruta, Deveronians, Chagrian, Twi'lek, Zabraks, Mirialans, etc, etc, etc.) are all descended from ancient human based strandcast lineages (most likely of the "prisoners with jobs" persuasion), customised and engineered in the very distant pre-history of the galaxy for colonization of near-habitable worlds during early centuries of terraforming efforts, that eventually escaped/were abandoned or otherwise propagated by various other means (willingly or otherwise.) Imagine for example that lekku of various designs could be engineered specifically to allow workers to cope better with arid environments by storing moisture in the form of fatty tissue (not unlike an camel's hump) and regulate body temperature (like an African elephant's ears.) Or that certain rather vivid skin-tones are either purely cosmetic for "domestic models", as a kind of artificially imposed organizational caste system, or to blend in within certain terrestrial environments, or indeed to stand out so they can be easily seen. Think all of this happening something of the order of 100,000 years prior to the Skywalker Saga. That allows for populations to speciate, hybridise, and migrate in countless ways over the millennia to allow for whatever the storytellers need it to, and not needing to really define who engineered them (though it could probably have just been other humans), and serves to feed into the idea that in the time before the Jedi and the Old Republic, the galaxy was a dark, lawless, and barbaric place to exist.

. . . But that's just me. Pure speculation with not a shred of evidence, and probably some that could easily tear it down. Anyone else's ideas are just as potentially valid, so the best advice is to just decide what works best for your own head canon, and go with that until something more interesting comes along, or they actually get to defining it in actual canon. Until then it's perfectly fine to just use your imagination for things like this.